# Why is `ulimit` not limiting the memory usage as I expect?

Tags: bash, memory-management, ulimit, resources

I am trying to limit the memory usage of a process

```
$ulimit -m 2
$/usr/bin/time -l ./myProcess arg1 arg2
```

The process run without being killed until `time` outputs

```
        7.00 real         4.83 user         2.16 sys
4154855424  maximum resident set size
         0  average shared memory size
         0  average unshared data size
         0  average unshared stack size
   1014384  page reclaims
         0  page faults
         0  swaps
         0  block input operations
         2  block output operations
         0  messages sent
         0  messages received
         0  signals received
         0  voluntary context switches
        15  involuntary context switches
```

showing that the limit has been overpassed despite the `ulimit -m 5` command line. I have also tried the options `-v` and `-l` but none of them seem to actually limit the memory usage. I also tried with `time` to make sure it would not fail to see the memory usage of a subprocess. Here are all limits after using all `-m`, `-v` and `-l`

```
$ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 3
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) 2
open files                      (-n) 256
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 709
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 2
```

If I limit the CPU time (`ulimit -t 3`), then it works fine and kill the process after 3 seconds.

**Question**

Is there something I misunderstand about `ulimit -m 5`? Is there a bug in my ulimit version?

Is there an alternative to `ulimit` to limit time and memory usage of a process (not necessarily the bash session)?

**Versions**

I am on `MAC OSX 10.11.6` and `bash version 3.2.57`.

**Related post**

[The post "ulimit not limiting memory usage"](https://superuser.com/questions/206233/ulimit-not-limiting-memory-usage) is very related but I don't think the accepted answer offer any solution on how to solve the problem

Comment: @dsstorefile mmhhh... ok. Well I think this settles the problem up. Do you want to make it an answer? Do you happen to know an alternative?

Comment: `ulimit -d` limits data-segment, `ulimit -v` limits address space (including code, shared libraries, mmaps, everything). OTOH,`cgroups` memory-counting includes the disk-cache. That can be rather surprising.

Comment: How to do it version: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44985/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process

Answer (score 3):

With modern Linux kernels, the `ulimit` is getting less and less meaningful with every release. You really cannot use `-v` because your version of glibc might prefer loading files with `mmap()` so you have to set `-v` large enough to include all files that the process is going to open. As a result, the `-v` flag cannot be used to limit physical RAM usage.

In addition, the `-m` flag does nothing so it cannot be used to limit physical memory usage, either.

Nowadays one has to use `cgroups` interface to kernel to limit physical RAM usage but the API is a bit hard to use, unfortunately. Perhaps one day we have some process similar to `nice` and `ionice` that can limit memory for a process given as a parameter.

In theory, with recent enough `systemd` you should be able to do something like

`systemd-run --scope --user -p MemoryMax=250M -- /path/to/program/to/use`

and it should magically work. There's no technical reason for this not working (because the underlying Linux `cgroup` feature does support the required things) but some `systemd` versions will just silently fail and not actually limit the memory usage. You can also add something like `-p MemoryHigh=200M` to `systemd-run` options if you want to push the program to lower memory consumption without killing it. Be warned though that exceeding `MemoryHigh` will slowdown the process quite a bit because kernel will be doing extra work to reclaim all the memory (including caches) away from that process to reduce memory usage. In many cases, you do not want that if you want to enforce the max limit.